# Why do all other windows minimize when I open a window from the dock?

Tags: mojave, dock, multitasking, window-manager, imac-pro

Clicking an app icon from the dock causes all other windows onscreen to minimize. Is this intended? Is there a way to configure it so selected app's most recent window gets placed on top without minimizing the other windows?

iMac Pro 2017 on Mojave 10.14.3

I'm running:
Karabiner
SensibleSideButtons
Snap
TinkerTool

Using:
USB Mouse and Keyboard

Comment: that's not the default behavior. I don't have any of those apps installed, so maybe one of those is causing it, but I wasn't able to see that behavior fiddling with settings in Dock or Mission Control.

Comment: This sounds like single-window-mode to me (which was a thing in long gone versions of macOS, but who knows, maybe it's still there). Can you check if the Terminal/commandline command "defaults read com.apple.dock single-app" brings up a result?

Comment: @Gummibando it returned 1

Sounds like that might be a lead. Is there a command to change that preference?

Comment: @dwightk good to know that it's not designed to be that frustrating. Hopefully I can get it functioning the way it should.

Comment: @TheronRogers Please check if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Terminal/commandline:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool false; killall Dock
```

My hunch is that you accidentially changed this setting in TinkerTool.

Comment: Writing the value via Terminal and signing back in fixed it but restarting the Dock after correcting the setting per your suggestion probably would've straightened it out too. I really appreciate your help. It's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Also found this to be a setting in TinkerTool so I probably toggled it accidentally. Oops.

Comment: I've never used TinkterTool and still had this issue. Must have been some other, not so obvious app.

Comment: @thaikolja TinkerTool is "only" a GUI for command line functions, including the one in the answer. There are many other GUI tools providing this functionality, but as the OP stated using TinkerTool in the question, the answer is specific to this app. Did the "defaults write…" command solve the problem for you?

Comment: @Gummibando Yes, it worked.